# How do I add a stroke to a mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Given the mesh shown below, I would like to change the color of the sides/walls from blue to white.

[image]

Ideally, I would like to have a way to create a new mesh that includes just the sides, but not the top, so that I can easily change colors later if needed.

Note that what is shown here is just one country, but I need to do this for a map showing all European countries, so looking for something that requires as little manual work as possible.

NB: In 2D Vector Art, we would call this a stroke/outline/border.

---

Note that some of the edges are quite complex, so things like Solidify Modifier do not work particularly well here. And if I create a duplicate of the mesh, then scale that up, I get parts where the original and the duplicate overlap.

[image]

Comment: Depending on your mesh (for this it would be good if you share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/), you could also use *Geometry Nodes* here. This would reduce the manual effort and make the whole thing procedural. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: I haven't worked with Geometry Nodes yet, so not sure how to go about that, but would be interested to try.

Comment: Don't worry, [Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry-nodes/info) are just a modifier that can be used to do a lot of fun things. Looks wilder than it is. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If *Geometry Nodes* are an option for you, here I show a very simplified example using a curve as a starting point:

[image]

1. First you add the *Geometry Nodes* modifier.
2. The Node `Resample Curve` evaluates the curve’s points based on the resolution attribute.
3. With `Fill Curve` you create a closed meh from it.
4. `Set Material` assigns a specific material to this geometry.
5. The node `Extrude Mesh` extrudes the created faces with the given value (along the normal of the faces, if no value was passed to *Offset*).
6. Finally, I assign another material to the upper faces, which are available to me as a selection after the extrusion on a socket.

Depending on your starting point and what exactly you want to achieve, this setup can be extended as much as you like.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it out. My result is vastly different, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbPsH.png Also noticed that in your file, the Extrude Mesh node seems to only do it on the Z axis, whereas in mine, it seems to do it on all axes.

Comment: @Ben What happens if you uncheck the *Individual* checkbox in the node `Extrude`? And have you disabled the *Solidify* modifier? ...but as I said: In case of *Geometry Nodes* it would be important if you could share the blend file, which at least contains the underlying source material/curve/mesh.

Comment: If I uncheck it, the white goes away, and I can only see blue. It only has the GeometryNodes modifier. Let me see if I can share it. I am trying the Blend Exchange.

Comment: I have uploaded the file. The rugged looking island near the top left is the one that I used for testing the Geometry nodes. Note that this was created from an svg, which did have strokes (but double strokes which causes issues). They look good in most cases, but unfortunately not all, hence why I'm trying to re-create them in Blender instead. https://blend-exchange.com/b/MO0Wal71

Comment: @Ben Do you still have the original SVG available? You could save yourself a lot of steps. With *Geometry Nodes* you would simply work on the original curves.

Comment: Yes, I do, but not sure how to upload it. Imgur won't allow svgs.

Comment: @Ben OK, if you have the original SVG curves available, then for the most part you should be able to directly use the answer I showed. This is based on the assumption that curves are your starting point. If you want to continue working on the current mesh, then you can use the following setup, in which I simply check the direction of the normals of the faces, and assign different materials to them accordingly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLsgZ.jpg

Comment: @Ben You could import the SVG into a blend file and share it via https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you for the SVG tip! So I imported the original SVG again and only added the Geometry Node to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAIvT.png That's much better, but not sure how to change the thickness of the white outline?

Comment: @Ben OK, well done, we are getting closer to the goal! ;-) You could additionally extrude the sides of the mesh a bit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri1W3.jpg

Comment: I have tried adding another Extrude Mesh node, yes. I have to use very small values, e.g. 0.0001, and the result doesn't really work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9xV.png

Comment: I have uploaded the updated Blend file here in case you want to try it: https://blend-exchange.com/b/VKwR3llR/

Comment: Just realised it also causes issues where two countries are touching each other. In those cases, I need the white line to be clearly visible from above.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the mesh shown below, I would like to change the color of the sides/walls from blue to white.

1. Select the mesh
2. Go to 'Edit Mode'
3. Press Numpad 1 to enter horizon view
4. Go to Wireframe Shading view mode
5. Make sure you are in 'Face Select Mode' (and not 'vertex select' mode)
6. Select all the side faces (drag select in the middle so you only select the side faces and not the top or bottom ones)
7. Create a new material (in your case, a white color)
8. Press 'Assign' to add that white material to the edges
9. Exit 'Edit Mode'

Done! Now you should have separate colors for your edges and your top/bottom! (And you can edit the colors anytime in the Material Properties panel)